# Take coordinates from Google map URL for my JSON

Tags: google-maps

I need to take coordinates from Google map URL for my JSON.
I am taking lat, lng, and zoom from URL.
But my mark doesn't appear on the same spot as on Google map mark.
For example here:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/ADRA+Laos/@17.8575854,102.1769446,8.81z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3124662d079f33c5:0xcef5f2b499df9a6e!8m2!3d17.9613965!4d102.6307923 
I take 
lat: 17.8575854,
lng: 102.1769446,
zoom: 8.81

I guess I am missing something that I have to take.
My mark is not far from original, but not on the same spot.
Please, say me what I am missing

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates after the @ sign are the center of the map, not the coordinates of the place. The coordinates of the place/marker are at the end of the URL: `!8m2!3d17.9613965!4d102.6307923`

```
17.9613965,102.6307923
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/js6r4hxo/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 17.9613965, lng: 102.6307923},
    zoom: 18
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```